# Getting Undefined using Props with Map function, how can it be resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-props, getserversideprops

I'm trying to integrate Mapbox to a tutorial page I'm working on using following code ang calling API:https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/5NPS, however instead of getting Object values I'm getting "undefined "

**AirBnbMap.js (component)**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Map from "react-map-gl";
import { getCenter } from "geolib";

function AirBnbMap({ searchResults }) {
  //Transform the search results objects in to
  //{ latitude: 52.516272, longitude: 13.377722 },
  //object

  const coordinates = searchResults.map((result) => ({
    longitude: result.long,
    latitude: result.lat,
  }));

  console.log(coordinates);

  //The latitude and longitude of the center of locations coordinates

  const center = getCenter(coordinates);

  const [viewState, setViewState] = useState({
    longitude: center.longitude,
    latitude: center.latitude,
    zoom: 3.5,
  });

  return (
    <Map
      {...viewState}
      onMove={(evt) => setViewState(evt.viewState)}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
      mapboxAccessToken={process.env.mapbox_key}
    />
  );
}
export default AirBnbMap;
```

**search.js (page)**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import InfoCard from "../components/InfoCard";
import AirBnbMap from "../components/AirBnbMap";

function Search({ searchResults }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  //ES6 Destrucuring
  const { location, startDate, endDate, noOfGuests } = router.query;

  const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd MMMM yy");
  const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), "dd MMMM yy");
  const range = `${formattedStartDate} - ${formattedEndDate}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <Header placeholder={`${location} | ${range} | ${noOfGuests} guests`} />
      <main className="flex ">
        <section className="flex-grow pt-14 px-6">
          <p className="text-xs">
            300+ Stays - {range} - for {noOfGuests} guests
          </p>
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-6">
            Stays in {location}
          </h1>

          <div className="hidden lg:inline-flex mb-5 space-x-3 text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
            <p className="button">Cancellation Flexibility</p>
            <p className="button">Type of Place</p>
            <p className="button">Price</p>
            <p className="button">Rooms and Beds</p>
            <p className="button">More filters</p>
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col">
            {searchResults?.map(
              ({ img, location, title, description, star, price, total }) => (
                <InfoCard
                  key={img}
                  img={img}
                  location={location}
                  title={title}
                  description={description}
                  star={star}
                  price={price}
                  total={total}
                />
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </section>

        <section className="hidden xl:inline-flex xl:min-w-[40%] sticky top-[76px] h-[calc(100vh-76px)]">
          <AirBnbMap />
        </section>
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const searchResults = await fetch("https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/5NPS").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  return {
    props: {
      searchResults,
    },
  };
}
```

Getting error:
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

[image]

However expecting Object value:
[image]

Comment: You have to actually pass the props to the component, they won't magically appear. `<AirBnbMap searchResults={searchResults } />`

Comment: Thanks. I just keep overlooking this.